# .txt Saving and naming the file

Tags: c, file

Thats the deal, I am trying to make and offline Email Manager, where you can write and store emails in different folders.
Written in .txt files that contain the basic information of an email (to:, from:, body :, etc). I am having issues on the following process.

-Each email has an ID that helps on searching and administration. I want to give the name of .txt files the ID related to the email that contains. So .... How can I create a .txt file that has the name of the ID and the ID is given by the user.

Thank you.

Comment: not sure what the question is. Do you know how to create a file?

Comment: [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) and `fopen`?

Comment: Read the chapter dealing with files in your C text book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a buffer to build your filename.

```
#define BUFFERSIZE 256 /* max size of a path */
FILE * fp ;
char buffer[BUFFERSIZE] ;
snprintf(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, "/path/to/file/%s.txt", your_id_string);
fp = fopen(buffer, "w+") ;
```